# Edit XML file with batch script

Tags: xml, batch-file, replace, xml-parsing, user-input

I am looking to edit an XML file located in `C:\CONFIG\TEST_CONFIG.XML` and replace 2 different values within.  I am looking to replace the following criteria with this file:

```
<test.tbl>
CONFIG!CONFIG2 |1 T |125 **TN###** |151 **TN###**
</TEST.tbl>

"|125 TN###" must equal %USERINPUT1%

"|151 TN###" must equal %USERINPUT2%
```

I have found other posts that come close but having difficulties getting around.

Another catch is I need to keep all the spacing and special characters.

Comment: Does that config line appear anywhere else in the file exactly the same way?

Comment: No, this does not appear anywhere else in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion

set USERINPUT1=First Value
set USERINPUT2=Second Field

for /F "delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N /C:"CONFIG!CONFIG2 |1 T |125 **TN###** |151 **TN###**" C:\CONFIG\TEST_CONFIG.XML') do set num=%%a
(for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" C:\CONFIG\TEST_CONFIG.XML') do (
   set "line=%%b"
   setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
   if "%%a" equ "%num%" (
      set "line=!line:|125 **TN###**=%USERINPUT1%!"
      set "line=!line:|151 **TN###**=%USERINPUT2%!"
   )
   echo(!line!
   endlocal
)) > temp.xml
move /Y temp.xml C:\CONFIG\TEST_CONFIG.XML
```

**EDIT**: *Example added*

input.xml:

```
<test.tbl>
<p>Support the free distribution of this forecast by visiting our sponsors website.<p><b>Select forecast - </b>
<a href="?fdate=140403">Tomorrow</a> / <a href="?fdate=140404">Friday</a> / <a href="?fdate=140405">Saturday</a><p><hr>
CONFIG!CONFIG2 |1 T |125 **TN###** |151 **TN###**
<h5>Viewing forecast for Thursday, 3rd April, 2014</h5><p>Forecast last reviewed on Wednesday, 02/04/14 at 16:17
</TEST.tbl>
```

output.xml:

```
<test.tbl>
<p>Support the free distribution of this forecast by visiting our sponsors website.<p><b>Select forecast - </b>
<a href="?fdate=140403">Tomorrow</a> / <a href="?fdate=140404">Friday</a> / <a href="?fdate=140405">Saturday</a><p><hr>
CONFIG!CONFIG2 |1 T First Value Second Field
<h5>Viewing forecast for Thursday, 3rd April, 2014</h5><p>Forecast last reviewed on Wednesday, 02/04/14 at 16:17
</TEST.tbl>
```

Be sure to use the right matching strings in the replacements. In your example you put:

```
CONFIG!CONFIG2 |1 T |125 **TN###** |151 **TN###**
```

in your data, but:

```
"|125 TN###" must equal %USERINPUT1%
"|151 TN###" must equal %USERINPUT2%
```

in the matching strings that missed the `**` in the data. I added the `**` in the replacements, otherwise they fail...

Comment: I am getting "The system cannot find the file 'findstr /N /C:"CONFIG!CONFIG2 |1 T |125 **TN###** |151 **TN###**" C:\CONFIG\TEST_CONFIG.XML.

Comment: Oops! There was a small bug... Fixed! `;-)`

Comment: This really messes with my XML file resulting in the following:
C:\CONFIG>(
set "line="  
 setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion  
 if "2279" EQU "576" (
set "line=!line:|125 **TN###**=123!"  
 set "line=!line:|151 **TN###**=456!" 
)  
 echo(!line!  
 endlocal
) 

This goes on and repeats itself for over 23,000 lines

Comment: Good catch, I was more using the "**" to highlight/bold the fields I needed changed. Although I did remove the "**" from the batch entirely now and still getting:  
C:\CONFIG>(
set "line="  
 setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion  
 if "2279" EQU "576" (
set "line=!line:|125 TN###=123!"  
 set "line=!line:|151 TN###=456!" 
)  
 echo(!line!  
 endlocal
) 

with over 27,000 lines

Comment: I suggest you to copy _my_ example data above, run the program and confirm that you get _my_ example output. If so, then you should analyze the differences of your real data vs. the example you posted that was the base for my program. Hint: execute `findstr /N /C:"CONFIG!CONFIG2 |1 T |125 TN### |151 TN###" C:\CONFIG\TEST_CONFIG.XML`; you should get _one_ result line...

Comment: You my man are a gentleman and a scholar!! THANK YOU, THANK YOU, THANK YOU.  Works like a dream!